# Como obter apenas o domínio de uma URL?

Tags: php, url

O domínio não é o do `localhost`.

Se o utilizador digita um link, por exemplo, `http://exemplo.com/pasta/pasta2/past/ficheiro.php`, eu pretendo que o PHP retorne apenas esta parte da url  `exemplo.com`

Comment: Verifique a variável $_SERVER, ela irá retornar os valores que precisa.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O PHP já tem uma função que separa todos os elementos de um URL.

É justamente a `parse_url`:

```
$url = 'http://exemplo.com/pasta/pasta2/past/ficheiro.php';
$elementos = parse_url($url);

echo $elementos['host']; // 'exemplo.com'
```

Se quiser uma parte específica utilize o segundo parâmetro:

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);  // 'exemplo.com'
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/jI64IM)**.

Estas são as opções para o segundo parâmetro:

```
 PHP_URL_SCHEME     // retorna string  - ex: http
 PHP_URL_HOST       // retorna string  - ex: site.com
 PHP_URL_PORT       // retorna inteiro - ex: 443
 PHP_URL_USER       // retorna string  - ex: admin
 PHP_URL_PASS       // retorna string  - ex: swordfish
 PHP_URL_PATH       // retorna string  - ex: /blog
 PHP_URL_QUERY      // retorna string  - ex: secao=esportes
 PHP_URL_FRAGMENT   // retorna string  - ex: ancora2
```

Se for usar mais de uma parte, melhor pegar o array inteiro:

```
$partes = parse_url($url); // retorna array associativo
```

e usar todas as partes que interessam:

```
echo $partes['scheme'].'://'.$partes['host'].$partes['path'];
```

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php