# pegar url do site

Tags: php

Bom, tenho a seguinte **url**:

```
http://www.site.com.br/pasta1/pasta2/arquivo.php?parametro1=234&&parametro2=sim
```

Gostaria de saber qual a variável do tipo `$_SERVER[]` que devolve apenas

```
http://www.site.com.br
```

Comment: Relacionado [**Como obter apenas o domínio de um link?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179155/3635) (não é dup, só comentado pra referenciar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Caso precise do restante da url você pode usar os argumentos `'REQUEST_URI'` e `'PATH_INFO'`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Documentação da função [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: obrigado! Falta de atenção da minha parte!

Comment: Disponha , aqui é pra isso mesmo, tirar dúvidas.